# How to solve these inequalities with floors and ceilings?

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to solve these two inequalities for $x$, as a function of the positive integer $n$:

$$
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
\ceil{\frac{2 x n}{\ceil{2 x}+2}} \geq n
\\
\ceil{\frac{\floor{2 x} n }{\floor{2 x}+2}} \geq n
$$

So far, the only progress I could made is remove the outer ceiling, since the ceiling is at least $n$ iff the thing inside the ceiling is larger than $n-1$. So I got:

$$
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
\frac{2 x n}{\ceil{2 x}+2} > n-1
\\
\frac{\floor{2 x} n }{\floor{2 x}+2} > n-1
$$

But I have no idea, how to make further progress on this?

Comment: Do you want an inequality of $x$ in terms of $n$ for every starting inequality or something else?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing one "ceiling" in the first equation? In the second equation you have two "floors".

Comment: @Tortar yes, an inequality of $x$ in terms of $n$, for each starting inequality separately.

Comment: @Oldboy Yes, the first inequality purposefully has only one ceiling (I got this inequality from some previous calculation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Now for the second inequality you can solve for $\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ as a whole, as you normally would for  a fractional inequality. For the first, set $m=\lceil 2x \rceil$, and solve $x$ in terms of $n$ *and* $m$, then impose the condition that $m-1<2x\le m$, which should give you the range of $x$ expressed in terms of $n,m$. Now take the union of all the ranges for each $m\in\mathbb Z$.

To give the reason why I suggested this complicated way for solving #1, let's look at an example where $n=3$. In fact, if $n=3$ then $\frac73 < x \le \frac52 $ or $\frac83 < x$. And "$\frac73 < x \le \frac52 $ or $\frac83 < x$" **as a whole** serves as the correct answer. For $n=4$ the answer splits into 3 parts, etc. Therefore, it is essential that you analyze *every possible* $m=\lceil 2x \rceil$, and then piece up all the possibilities.

Comment: The idea for the second inequality worked fine and I got $\lfloor 2x \rfloor \geq 2n-1$. For the first inequality, I first replaced the $2xn$ with $\lceil 2x \rceil$ and got the necessary condition $\lceil 2x \rceil \geq 2n-1$. Then I got back to the original inequality and got $2x > (1-1/n)(2+\lceil 2x \rceil)$. Obviously, to get a lower bound on $x$, the right-hand side should be as small as possible, so I substituted $\lceil 2x \rceil  = 2n-1$ and got $2x>(1-1/n)(2n+1)$.

Comment: @Erel Actually you have a gap in your reasoning. You do not want a lower bound on $x$. Instead you want to solve for $x$. For instance, when $n=3$, the valid range of $x$ splits into two intervals, and even more for larger $n$.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I edited my answer, so it might clear some confusion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificiation! It is indeed quite confusing that such a small change in the inequality leads to a discontinuous solution.

Answer (score 2):

For the second one ,

split the two cases $\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil} \floor{2 x}+2 > 0 \iff x\geq-\frac{1}{2} $ and $\floor{2 x}+2 < 0 \iff x \leq -\frac{1}{2} $.

Taking first case :

$$
\frac{\floor{2 x} n }{\floor{2 x}+2} > n-1 \iff \floor{2 x} >2(n-1) \iff x \geq n-\frac{1}{2} 
$$

So we have $x \geq n-\frac{1}{2} $.

For the other case we have $
 x \leq n-\frac{1}{2} 
$.

So the solution is $x \leq- \frac{1}{2} \cup x \geq n-\frac{1}{2} $.

The first one can be solved with the same reasoning, splitting it in subcases.

Comment: For the first one, in the positive case, I get $2xn > (n-1)(\lceil 2x \rceil + 2)$. Now it is not clear how to proceed since $2x$ and $\lceil 2x \rceil$ do not cancel out

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-Let $f_n(x)$ your first function and consider $g(x)=\dfrac{2 x}{\lceil 2x \rceil+2}$.

What you want is $f_n(x)\ge n$ and for this you need $g(x)\ge1$. Solving $g(x)\gt1$ because it is clear that $g(x)$ cannot be equal to $1$ for $x$ real. Try to find $\color{red}{x\le{-1.5}}$.

Similarly for your second inequation.

Comment: I think it should be not $g(x)\geq 1$ but $g(x) > 1 - 1/n$.

Comment: Maybe. Thank you. Anyway all $x$ works in the mentioned solution.